# Graphing $[-2,2] \times [-1,3]$ $-$ $\left\{\left(x,y\right):\ x^2+y^2\le 4\right\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graphing-functions, relations

Question:

Let S = $[-2,2] \times [-1,3]$

Let T = $\left\{\left(x,y\right):\ x^2+y^2\le 4\right\}$

Graph $S$ $-$ $T$

Attempt:

I know that  $S$ is a shaded rectangle in the given boundaries. $T$ is a shaded circle (boundary included) of radius $ 2$. $S-T$ means everything in $S$ that is not in $T$. I am not sure how to graph $S - T$.

Comment: It's the rectangle with the circle *removed*.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Draw the shaded rectangles, color with red color.

Draw the shaded circle, color it with blue and then remove anything with blue colors, that is remove the whole circle, even if any part of it was previously colored in red.

The remaining region is $S-T$.

Comment: In $S-T$ $[-2,2]$ and $-1$ boundary wouldn't be included right?

Comment: The boundary of the circle will not be included.  The boundary of the rectangle that are not in the circle will.

Comment: Will the boundary of the circle inside the rectangle change. If it is solid it, will it change to dotted?

Comment: The remaining region will become dotted. Any part of the circle, including the boundary, are to be removed.